# How to set the value of QSpinBox to max when value above max is entered?

Tags: c++, qt

The default behavior of Qt's SpinBox widget is very undesirable for my application.  If the maximum value is 998, and the user tries to type "999", the SpinBox will get a value of 99, which is very far from what the user wanted.

Is there an option or alternate widget that would instead acquire the value of 998 in this scenario?

Edit: Okay I've started working on it via the subclassing method, but it's not quite working as anticipated.

Header file:

```
// myspinbox.h

#ifndef MYSPINBOX_H
#define MYSPINBOX_H


#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QValidator>

class MySpinBox : public QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MySpinBox(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

   // QValidator::State validate(QString &text, int &pos) const override;

    void fixup(QString &input) const override;
};

#endif // MYSPINBOX_H
```

Source file:

```
// myspinbox.cpp

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <iostream>
#include "myspinbox.h"

MySpinBox::MySpinBox(QWidget *parent) : QSpinBox(parent) {}

//QValidator::State MySpinBox::validate(QString &text, int &pos) const {
//    return QValidator::Acceptable;
//}

void MySpinBox::fixup(QString &input) const {
    std::cout << "fixup called on input: " << input.toStdString() << std::endl;
    int int_val = input.toInt();
    int max_val = this->maximum();
    if (int_val > max_val) {
        input = QString::number(max_val);
        std::cout << "Max val is " << max_val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The message `fixup called on input...` is never being displayed.

---

In the [QSpinBox](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/widgets/qspinbox.cpp) source code, there is a function
`QVariant QSpinBoxPrivate::validateAndInterpret(QString &input, int &pos, QValidator::State &state) const` which in lines 1045 to 1050 is adjusting the input value if it is not within the allowed range.  I'm not sure if the given suggestion to override `fixup` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `QSpinBox` than override this two methods:

1. [QValidator::State QSpinBox::validate(QString &text, int &pos) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#validate)
2. [void QAbstractSpinBox::fixup(QString &input) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#fixup)

Note that you don't want to annoy user with to strong constraints what can be typed in text edit, so test it carefully and think how user can feel in different situation.

Here is code sample, using C++11:

```
class AltSpinBox : public QSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QSpinBox::QSpinBox;

protected:
    void fixup(QString &input) const;
    QValidator::State validate(QString &text, int &pos) const;
};

void AltSpinBox::fixup(QString &input) const
{
    auto isOk = false;
    auto value = input.toInt(&isOk, displayIntegerBase());
    if (isOk) {
        value = qBound(minimum(), value, maximum());
        input = QString::number(value, displayIntegerBase());
    } else {
        QSpinBox::fixup(input);
    }
}

QValidator::State AltSpinBox::validate(QString &text, int &pos) const
{
    auto isOk = false;
    auto value = text.toInt(&isOk, displayIntegerBase());
    if (isOk) {
        if (value >= minimum() && value <= maximum())
            return QValidator::Acceptable;
        return QValidator::Intermediate;
    } else {
        return QSpinBox::validate(text, pos);
    }
}
```

I've test it and it works like it should. Probably you like to tweak it a bit.

Comment: This does not seem to be working.  Without overriding `validate` I can't even type in a number larger than the max value, and `fixup` is not getting called.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it wouldn't work without updating the `validate` method, but I didn't know the appropriate way to do it.  The sample code you gave is very informative.